# Is there a good non-US based alternative to Firebase?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, firebase, backfire

Question has been asked by another person but not answered:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22134739/is-there-a-good-alternative-to-firebase-for-realtime-apps-with-backbonejs

I'm using Firebase and Backbone (Backfire) to create a social network, Firebase itself is close to perfectly integrated into Backbone syntax-wise.

My goal was to make it as privacy-oriented as possible, since German law wouldn't allow me to spy on the users to begin with. Here is the problem with Firebase:

> In Response to Legal Process We also may disclose the information we
>   collect in order to comply with the law, a judicial
>   proceeding, court order, or other legal process, such as in response
>   to a court order or a subpoena.

Which means the US Government could spy into the user data and there is nothing I can do about it from here, since US law applies.

Is there an alternative service that will either allow me to run my own server, or that is not US based? I'm not able to find a service that has been integrated nearly as good.

Comment: It's a good question, but off-topic here (just as the other one was). If Firebase is cloud-based, then it looks like the answer is no anyway - unless you get in touch with the firm that runs this service. Still, if they were to make an exception in your case, and if you need to be careful enough to worry about this sort of thing, they might be legally compelled to supply you modified binaries that opened a back-door anyway. Can you choose a different platform?

Comment: thanks for answering, the goal is to create a realtime Backbone application, Firebase itself isn't necessarily required.
Firebase just happened to have managed the backboneJs integration best.Its it's privacy policy and server location that worries us.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Recommendation requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow. You might have better luck at [Webmasters Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/). Note the question you're linking to has not been answered for the very same reason.

Comment: thanks @Boaz I will move this question there

Comment: It's a trade-off, then; decide which of those conflicting things is most important to you. It's good that you care about this stuff, but it's worth noting that a number of US tech firms do too, and are trying to change the situation in their country. See the [Dropbox principles](https://www.dropbox.com/transparency/principles) for a great example.